# Can any one tell what type of conversion is this

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

[image]

I will have the input as the left hand side 11 digits and the output should be preceeding to that or can any one tell how can i get that ouput byu taking those inputs as byte array

Comment: I'm not overly sure you're not violating some kind of privacy regulation here. Where was this sample taken from?

Comment: So what type do you have the data in a `byte[]`? Looks like you have some binary data being represented as Hex matrix and some ASCII. Kind of like you copied it from the Eventvwr.exe or some Hex editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Example of first line
```

@changed to support dot
    string[] line = "82 44 b4 2e 39 39 39 39 39 35".Split(' ');

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[line.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++) {
  int candidate = Convert.ToInt32(line[i], 16);
  if (!(!(candidate < 0x20 || candidate > 127)))
    candidate = 46; //.
  bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(candidate);
}

string s =  System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: @James : can i have it using  2.0

Comment: Can any one give me this in 2.0 please this works for me in 2008 but i am doing myu project in 2005

Comment: This works good except instead of .D4. this is dispalying ?D?.

Comment: .net 2.0 I think has a method called ConvertAll which is a generic method that takes a predicate even though my example didn't use it..

Comment: @JAmes thanks but as i said all are displaying correct except `.D4.` in this place i am getting this `?D?.`

Comment: Ok but still i am getting the output as .D.. but required is .D4.

Answer (score 3):

This is far from optimized, but this should work

```
int code = Convert.ToInt32("0x" + "82", 16);  //this is your first char
code = code >= 0x20 && code < 0x7f ? code : 0x2E;
byte b = Convert.ToByte(code);  
string txt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { b });
```

Comment: I am getting `?` instead of `.`

Comment: If you're wanting a . instead of a ?, then check out my edit which using something like what spender suggests.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the input as a byte array, then this should give you the string;

```
string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(input); // where "input" is your byte[]
```

Comment: i need a small favour how can i write that in to bytes i tried declare the whole as byte array but i am getting an error

Comment: But this is giving the output as the given input

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: I have shown in the image itself i will give this as input `82 44 b4 2e 39 39 39 39 39 35` and output should be `.D4.999995` what `James Kyburz` given work fyn excpet that as i mentioned for his answer as comment

Comment: Did you try the code provided by Frédéric Hamidi? It works better than what I've posted above anyway.

Comment: Ya even that displaying the same output which i given as input

Answer (score 3):

That encoding *seems* to be `ASCII`, but some of the characters have their high bit set for some reason. You can clear that bit and use [Encoding.ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx) to build a string from your byte array:

```
string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
    yourByteArray.Select(b => (byte) (b & 0x7F)).ToArray());
```

**EDIT:** If you can't use LINQ, you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourByteArray.Length; ++i) {
    yourByteArray[i] &= 0x7F;
}

string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(yourByteArray);
```

Comment: Oops sorry to mention i am using 2.0

Comment: But this is giving the output as the given input

Comment: @user552236, I'm not sure to understand what you mean. Do you want to ignore the high bit (so e.g. `0xd4` becomes `T`), *and* replace all non-printable characters with dots?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

```
// Convert the number expressed in base-16 to an integer.
int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
```

This was taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] bytes=new byte[]{0xf3,0x28,0x48,0x78,0x98};
var output=string.Concat( 
    bytes.Select(b => (char) (b >= 0x20 && b<0x7f ? b :(byte)'.') ).ToArray()
);
```

Comment: Oops sorry to mention i am using 2.0

Comment: I think adding a ToArray should fix. See above